# User friendly way to distribute Python Application

Tags: python, macos, exe, software-distribution, dmg

What could be the best way to distribute a python application to both windows and mac user without scaring them away during the installation process?

I'm writing a software which will be of help to my university's students. This software will be used by student of various discipline, a lot from those which have little to no programming background.

It would be best if there are some one click *magic happens* solution to the installation.

How should I go about doing them? Please advice!

Comment: You can look at [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/).

Comment: I'm tempted to vote to close as "too broad" or "off-topic because requesting tool recommendation," but I feel like this is also a genuinely useful question and I'm interested in potential answers.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty broad question.  The "best way" to distribute any software is to use a software distribution/systems management suite. It takes time to implement but once done the time savings is *enormous*.  There are several suites that will do this; I believe that AirWatch will work as will ThingWorx, Helix Device Cloud, and others.  These solutions can do what is called a "required distribution" which will simple force the software down.  There's not even a click; the software is just there as of the date you specify.

Now, if you don't want to invest time in a solution like this, then use the MSI format for Windows.  That is a superior way to install software - the user double-clicks on the software and, if you've done the MSI a certain way, the install happens.  There's a user decision to install which some won't take advantage of.  Again, that only works on Windows, sorry.  I'm not versed in Mac installations but I'm sure that there's a way to build installers for Mac as well.

If your users get scared during a normal software install, well, you've got a different problem.  If they're familiar with computers at all, they've seen software install before and have most likely done it.